# How to overflow background cover to be visibile when using scale transform to make the div smaller?

Tags: css, overflow, css-transforms, background-size

1. I have an absolute div (needs to be **absolute**).
2. The absolute div has a background-image with the background-size set to cover (size **cover** necessary)
3. I'm using a css transform to scale the div upon hover to a value less than 1, for example, scale(0.7)

Issue: I want the cover background-image to overflow beyond the div when it's scaled down.

Why I need it: The image is transparent with different graphics floating around and of the background-size cover so when browsing in a mobile, the transform crops graphics on the edge of the div and scales the div.

CSS solutions only please.

Edit: CSS + js solutions will do.

Example: the outer div is supposed to represent a mobile browser window.

```css
.chivoyage{
    position:absolute; 
    top:0px; 
    right:0px; 
    bottom:0px; 
    left:0px; 
    background-image:url('http://clipart.info/images/ccovers/1495916688repin-image-stars-png-transparent-stars-on-pinterest.png'); 
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center center;
    transition: all 1s ease-out 0s;
    cursor:pointer;
    }

    .chivoyage:hover{
    transform: scale(0.8);
    }

.window-mobile{
width:150px; height:300px; position:relative; border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="window-mobile"><div class="chivoyage"><div></div>
```

```
<div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after some thought, I arrived at a solution.
Basically, background-size: cover 
logically equals

1. background-size: 100% auto
   if the width:height ratio of image is lower than that of container
2. background-size: auto 100%
   if the width:height ratio of image is higher than that of container

So I ended up calculating the ratio using naturalheight and naturalwidth and with an if statement, I get which background-size to apply, thus maintaining the behaviour as cover while being able to work with the values via js to transform background-image.

On a side note, if you need to work with background-size:contain, just calculate the ratio and do the opposite (1. would be auto 100% and 2. would be 100% auto)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `scale` just try background size , on hover reduce the size. Have a look at the code

```css
.chivoyage{
position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background: url(http://clipart.info/images/ccovers/1495916688repin-image-stars-png-transparent-stars-on-pinterest.png)no-repeat center;
    background-size: 270%;
    transition: all 1s ease-out 0s;
    cursor: pointer;
    }

    .chivoyage:hover{
        background-size: 200%;
    }

.window-mobile{
width:150px; height:300px; position:relative; border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="window-mobile"><div class="chivoyage"><div></div>
```

Comment: Then try with a inner div, make it absolute and give it that background image and width 150%, and on hover to the parent div make it 100%,

Comment: I thought about that. See point 2, I mention I need size cover. The problem with using an increased background-size is that I need it to cover sized always. An arbitrary value like 270% won't be good for different ratios and sizes of windows. Cover makes sure it fills out without going over.

Comment: the 100% always refer to its parent div, so you can use 270% it wont effect on small size screen, because of course you reduce the size of the div as well. i think you can go with it

Comment: Had to edit the first comment, hadn't refreshed window so replies not chronological but here's the main thing. Cover makes sure to fill up the box without going over both dimensions(x and y). An arbitrary percentage value doesn't ensure that.